# «Глагол + наречие» — один член предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, глаголы, сказуемые, словосочетания, наречия

Является ли словосочетание *глагол + наречие* одним членом предложения (сказуемым) в данном примере? Почему? Какое средство синтаксической связи?

*Он увидел её и **пошёл прочь**.*

Прочь — так же часть сказуемого и это цельное словосочетание?  Или прочь — обстоятельство?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется, *прочь* будет **обстоятельством**.

*Пошел* — самостоятельное простое глагольное сказуемое. Оно не нуждается в конкретизации, а само по себе имеет смысл. Мы можем сказать просто: он пошёл, — и смысл будет ясен. А можем добавить обстоятельство: Пошёл куда? **прочь/домой/на улицу**.

Вероятно, задавая этот вопрос, вы хотели понять, является ли *пошёл прочь* составным именным сказуемым. Чтобы убедиться, что перед вами **не составное именное сказуемое**, попробуйте поменять предполагаемую связку на форму глагола *быть*. Если замена невозможна — перед вами **не составное именное сказуемое**. Например:

Он *казался* грубым / Он *был* грубым — замена возможна, перед нами **составное именное сказуемое**.

В вашем примере замена невозможна.

Таким образом, *прочь* не является частью сказуемого — оно обстоятельство.